# How to make use of :id returned by stateParams of stateProvider in angularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

Am looking to read & display this JSON array of objects.

```
[
{ 
"pictitle":"title1 ", 
"thumbpicurl":"url1",
"bigpicurl":"url2",
"picdescription":"text text" 
}, 
{ 
"pictitle":"title2 ", 
"thumbpicurl":"url1",
"bigpicurl":"url2",
"picdescription":"text text" 
},
]
```

JSON is served by this factory.

```
angular.module('picService', ['ngResource'])
.factory('picsFactory',function($resource){
  return $resource('pictures.json',{},{
  'getData':  {method:'GET', isArray:true}
  }
  );
});
```

This Markup displays mini thumbnails using the thubmpicURL of the JSON data.

```
    <div class="miniImages">
        <a href="/home/{{$index}}">
        <img src="{{pic.thumbpicurl}}" class='thumbnail'/> </a>
    </div>
```

Am using stateProvider for routing to display enlarged version of the picture when user selects a thumbnail.

```
  $stateProvider.state( 'home/:id', {
    url: '/home/:id',
    views: {
      "main": {
        controller: 'picCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'home/pics-detail.tpl.html'
      }
    } 
    });
```

First controller returns the JSON picture data.

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function HomeController( $scope,picsFactory ) {
  picsFactory.getData(function(picturedata){
  $scope.picParams = picturedata;
  });
})
```

Second controller is looking to set properties of each picture object. Am not sure what is the correct syntax to set the stateParams to the picture object.

```
.controller('picCtrl', function picController( $scope, $stateParams ) {
  $scope.picture = $scope.picParams[$stateParams.id];
})
;
```

I get this error in the debuge console. I think it doesn't like my **$scope.picParams[$stateParams.id]** in picCtrl controller.

Is this the correct way to make use of $stateParams

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

--
**ANSWER:**

I modified picCtrl to inject picsFactory and with this change it looks to work now.

```
.controller('picCtrl', function picController( $scope, $stateParams, picsFactory ) {
  picsFactory.getData(function(picturedata){
  $scope.picture = picturedata[$stateParams.id];
   });

})
;
```

Comment: Can you reproduce that in Fiddle/Plunker? will be great

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this could be that the async call of `getData` on `HomeCtrl` may not be complete before your second controller `picCtrl` is initialized and hence picParams is null.

Also `HomeCtrl` should be parent state or declared on parent html of `ui-view` for the `picCtrl` to be able to access what has been set by `HomeCtrl`